how do I convince springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui to use my custom fake_api.yml?
I have:

Added implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0' to my build.gradle
Created my fake_api.yml file (and verified it at https://editor.swagger.io)
Put my fake_api.yml file in src/main/resources/static.  I can download the file by hitting http://localhost:8080/fake_api.yml

Now I add this to application.properties:
springdoc.api-docs.path=/fake_api.yml
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true

If I hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, I get a Swagger UI, but it says "No operations defined in spec!".  Even more interesting, if I now hit http://localhost:8080/fake_api.yml, I get a JSON response that seems to be auto-generated.
If I set springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false, then hitting http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html gives me a 404 error.
How can I configure my system to provide a Swagger UI, but use my handwritten fake_api.yml file?
P.S.  I looked at Unable to load custom openapi.yaml file using springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui, but setting springdoc.swagger-ui.url doesn't seem to chang anything

I seem to have cracked this....

Put your YAML file in src/main/resources/static (mine is called fake_api.yml).  Test this by trying to hit http://localhost:8080/fake_api.yml, and it should download the file.
in src/main/resources/application.properties, add:

# must be set for the swagger UI to be available
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true

# this is where Swagger will look for the API definition.
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/fake_api.yml

DO NOT set springdoc.api-docs.path=/fake_api.yml in application.properties.  If you do, Swagger will auto-generate the API documentation and serve it at that url, overriding your fake_api.yml
At this point, you should be able to hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html and see a Swagger interface for the API defined in fake_api.url.
And just a note for "future me"....
You can control the URL for the swagger documentation by setting springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html
